# Why isn't my simple object converting to an Immutable.Map() with Immutable.fromJS({})

Tags: immutable.js

Why isn't my simple object converting to an Immutable.Map() with Immutable.fromJS({})

**Here it is with Map()** - works as expected

```
> var mymap = Immutable.Map({test:0})
undefined
> mymap
Map { "test": 0 }
```

**Here it is with .fromJS()** - does not work as I expect

```
> var mymap = Immutable.fromJS({test: 0});
undefined
> mymap
{ test: 0 }
> mymap.set('test', 1)
TypeError: mymap.set is not a function
    at repl:1:7
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:32:31)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:31:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:308:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:489:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
> mymap
{ test: 0 }
> typeof mymap
'object'
```

Using

- Node.js 6.3.0
- Immutable.js 3.8.1

**Update 8/18/16**:
@oluckyman pointed out in a comment that this happens in the console.  And as the question shows, that is where I'm seeing it too.  I haven't yet tested to see if it happens when running in a node file, but the results from the console don't inspire confidence.

Comment: Facing same problem here. It’s only in `node` console. In browser works well

Comment: Seeing this behavior in Node only as well. In the REPL:
`> c = fromJS([0,{x: 3}, [4, 5]])

    > List [ 0, [object Object], List [ 4, 5 ] ]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are importing them fine? It should work well.

I just tested and they seem to be working fine. Here is the [link](https://jsbin.com/dirafuraxi/edit?html,js,console) to my jsbin